# Concurrent webApi calls stuck on prod env only

Tags: iis, concurrency, webapi

i'm having hard time figuring out a blocking issue on a client.

the situation is:

A WebSite on Azure WebApp with Vue and Js and some api deployed on a vm on azure.

one (and only one) of the apis is having serious issues lately. Basically we upload images on a DAM using web api 2.0 as a wrapper.

When we upload multiple images together, the client application iterate through an array and perform X calls to the server(form-Data with images around 1mb). those calls arrives pretty much simultaneously on the server.

on dev/qa, everything works fine. i can see from the logs that different thread are created to handle X requests.

on production, this doesn't work anymore. different thread are created but basically the first request freeze everything for a couple of minutes (iis timeout), not even the log file is updated, and return a "task was canceled" error.

From the log I can see that the LogControllerHandler (that overrides the send async method) is hit but the controller is not; this seems not to happen with small images (150 kb).

the iis on prod and QA should be exactly the same, but for some reason, on prod I got this behavior I cannot figure out.

Any pointer would be apreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Without any code (please read about how to ask a question on SO), it's very difficult to guess, but it sounds like you aren't doing async/await properly.   Please post your controller code.

Comment: Have you analyzed the dump file? What was the frozen thread doing and did you see any dead lock there?Besides, did you see something wrong in IIS log/httperr log or event viewer?

Comment: @Neil I didn't put any code for 2 reason. my code used to work till start of january and my controller is not hit. everything freeze at LogControllerHandler. but all my controller are synchronous.

Comment: It  sounds like something changed in your environment. Did you apply update before this issue happen?